# JMS Job queue with Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, jms, message-queue

I am looking for some grails plugin which would do the following

- Submission of jobs(Calling a remote method asynchronously)
- Broker should be running from different host

Which plugin fits best for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [JMS](http://grails.org/plugin/jms) plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have seen ActiveMQ, jms-routing, Want to know which fits the best here, Could you please add some experience with this plugin if you have used this one

Comment: I only used the JMS plugin with a local ActiveMQ instalation, but you should have no problem using it with a remote broker. You only need this plugin and the broker running. Check this exemple on how to use an ActiveMQ broker with the plugin: http://gpc.github.com/grails-jms/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Plugging%20in%20a%20JMS%20Provider.html