# Grails JMS Plugin to WebLogic JMS Server

Tags: grails, jms, weblogic

Has anyone configured Grails 2.x JMS Plugin to send/receive messages to a remote WebLogic JMS Server? I've tried resources.groovy configurations like this with no luck:

```
jmsConnectionFactory(InitialContext, [
 "INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY": "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
 "PROVIDER_URL": "t3://remote-host:7001",
 "SECURITY_PRINCIPAL": "weblogic",
 "SECURITY_CREDENTIALS": "weblogic"])
```

Comment: Can you please give some additional details?  Failing at startup or runtime, stacktrace, etc?

Comment: The configuration I gave is way off-base, I get an error from JMS plugin about not being able to find the jmsConnectionFactory. I'm looking for anyone who has and example of connecting Grails to WebLogic JMS.

Comment: if you could help on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436137/jms-job-queue-with-grails)

Answer (score 0):

Not much resources with complete answers are on net about sending/receiving JMS in Grails with remote Weblogic server, so I figured out 2-3 years ago a **working** solution, **without need of any plugins**.

1. Make sure that at least [Weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13717/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT379) wlthint3client.jar is in lib directory.
2. Setting up JMS **listener**:

   - in conf/spring/resources.groovy:

     ```
     // Weblogic's JMS setup on Grails
     jndiTemplate(org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) {
         environment = [
                 "java.naming.factory.initial"     : "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
                 "java.naming.provider.url"        :  "t3://host.name.mustbe.same.as.configured.on.server.side:port_number",
                 "java.naming.security.principal"  : "wlsadmin",
                 "java.naming.security.credentials": "password"
         ]
     }


     //
     // listener
     //
     jmsListenerConnectionFactory(org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean) {
         jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
         jndiName     = "jms.checkonserver.QueueConnectionFactory"
     }

     jmsListenerDestinationResolver(org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver) {
         jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
         cache = false
     }

     userListenerCredentialsConnectionFactory(org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter){
         targetConnectionFactory = ref(jmsListenerConnectionFactory)
     }

     standardListenerJmsTemplate(org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate) {
         connectionFactory   = ref(userListenerCredentialsConnectionFactory)
         destinationResolver = ref(jmsListenerDestinationResolver)
     }

     jmsListenerMessageListener(org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter, ref("myListenerService")) { 
         defaultListenerMethod = "onMessage"
     }

     standardListenerJmsListenerContainer(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
         connectionFactory   = ref(jmsListenerConnectionFactory)
         destinationResolver = ref(jmsListenerDestinationResolver)
         messageListener = jmsListenerMessageListener
         destinationName     = "jms.checkonserver.MessagesQueue"
     }
     ```
   - in services/myListenerService.groovy:

     ```
     package app

     class MyListenerService {

           static transactional = false
           static scope = "prototype"

      def onMessage(msg) {
           log.info "JMS msg received."
           try {
               String txtmsg = new String(msg as String)
               log.info txtmsg
           } catch (e) {
               log.error e
           }
       }
     }
     ```
3. Setting up JMS **sender** :

   - in conf/spring/resources.groovy:

     ```
             jmsSenderConnectionFactory( org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean) {
                 jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
                 jndiName     = "jms.checkonseerver.QueueConnectionFactory" 
             }

             jmsSenderDestinationResolver(org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver) {
                 jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
                 cache = false
             }

             userSenderCredentialsConnectionFactory(org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter){
                 targetConnectionFactory = ref(jmsSenderConnectionFactory)
             }

             standardSenderJmsTemplate(org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate) {
                 connectionFactory   = ref(userSenderCredentialsConnectionFactory) //
                 destinationResolver = ref(jmsSenderDestinationResolver)
             }
     ```
   - in service/myJmsSenderService.groovy:

     ```
     package app

     import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator

     import javax.jms.JMSException
     import javax.jms.Message
     import javax.jms.Session

     class MyJmsSenderService {

          static transactional = false
          static scope = "prototype"

          def standardSenderJmsTemplate

          def sendMessage(txt) { 
               MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws
                JMSException {
                   return session.createTextMessage(txt)
                }
               }

             standardSenderJmsTemplate.send( "jms.checkonserver.SendingQueue", messageCreator)

             log.info "JMS message send: ${txt}"

          } 
      }
     ```